# Как не убирать ползунок на автомате?

Tags: html, css

Сделал плавную менюшку, но есть одна проблема - когда я убираю курсор с меню, оно пропадает не плавно, а как-то дерганно, сначала скрывая ползунок, а потом и разделы меню.

Как можно исправить?

```css
.sub-menu-parent {
  position: relative;
  left: 7%;
}

.sub-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -20%;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-2em);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}

.sub-menu-parent:focus .sub-menu,
.sub-menu-parent:focus-within .sub-menu,
.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
  overflow-y: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
  height: 400px;
}

body {
  font: 18px/1.4 sans-serif;
}

nav a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #F55;
}

nav ul,
nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav>ul {
  background: rgb(167, 0, 111);
  text-align: center;
}

nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: solid 1px rgb(167, 0, 111);
}

nav>ul>li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgb(110, 0, 74);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" style="width: 500px;">
  <nav>
    <ul style="display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;">
      <li class="sub-menu-parent" tab-index="0">
        <a href="#">Меню сайта</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li class="sub-menu-parent" tab-index="0">

        <a href="#">Объявления</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Советую вам изучить псевдо класс `:where` / `:is`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ползунок" нужно показывать всегда, у него никогда не было плавности, так что его переносим в стили вне `:hover`'а, тоже самое делаем с высотой меню. Эти пропорции (`overflow-y` и `height`) никогда (за некоторым исключением) не имеют плавности, так что их нужно переносить в стили где они всегда применяются, не завися от действий пользователя.

```css
.sub-menu-parent {
  position: relative;
  left: 7%;
}

.sub-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -20%;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-2em);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 400px;
}

.sub-menu-parent:focus .sub-menu,
.sub-menu-parent:focus-within .sub-menu,
.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
}

body {
  font: 18px/1.4 sans-serif;
}

nav a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #F55;
}

nav ul,
nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav>ul {
  background: rgb(167, 0, 111);
  text-align: center;
}

nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: solid 1px rgb(167, 0, 111);
}

nav>ul>li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.sub-menu {
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgb(110, 0, 74);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" style="width: 500px;">
  <nav>
    <ul style="display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;">
      <li class="sub-menu-parent" tab-index="0">
        <a href="#">Меню сайта</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li class="sub-menu-parent" tab-index="0">

        <a href="#">Объявления</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">texttexttexttexttext</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```